# Search array of arrays with array_column, return corresponding value at (n) column. How?

Tags: php, arrays

The following code works. I have the following array of arrays that I would like to search with array_column and return corresponding value at (n) column. At the moment my code only returns a column to the right or a column to the left.

**Existing working code**

```
function getField_UnitPrice($xmc) {
    // Key values MUST ALWAYS BE UNIQUE.
    // Values on the left.
    $xmpd_db = array(
    1 => array('EA_WTRESRVD', '122.67'),
    2 => array('EA_WTRESRV', '184.00'),
    3 => array('EA_FEEASBT', '300.00'),
    4 => array('GL_WTREXTWP', '0.64'),
    5 => array('GL_WTREXTWPA', '0.96')

  );

  $search_result = array_column($xmpd_db, 1, 0);
  return $search_result[$xmc];

}
```

As you can see, this function returns a price for the code you look up but what if the array of arrays has more than 2 columns?

I think the answer lies in the line of code below but no matter how I change these indexes nothing more than the code column displays..

```
$search_result = array_column($xmpd_db, 1, 0);
```

**Goal**

```
function getField_Target($xmc, $column_index)
    {
    // Key values MUST ALWAYS BE UNIQUE.
    // Values on the left.
    $xmpd_db = array(
    1 => array('EA', 'WTRESRVD', 'EMERGENCY SERVICE CALL', '122.67'),
    2 => array('EA', 'WTRESRV', 'EMERGENCY SERVICE CALL AFTER HOURS', '184.00')

  );

  $search_result = array_column($xmpd_db, 0, 1);
  return $search_result[$xmc];

    }
```

**Solution**

```
/* $field, 1, 0 = EA */
$unit_of_measure = getField_Target($field, 1, 0);
/* $field, 1, 1 = WTRESRVD*/
$code = getField_Target($field, 1, 1);
/* $field, 1, 2 = EMERGENCY SERVICE CALL*/
$code_desc = getField_Target($field, 1, 2);
/* $field, 1, 3 = 000.00*/
$code_price = getField_Target($field, 1, 3);

// Call
echo $unit_of_measure . " - " . $code . " - " . $code_desc . " - " . $code_price . "<br>";

function getField_Target($xmc, $column_index = 1, $column_value = 3) {
    // Key values MUST ALWAYS BE UNIQUE.
    // Values on the left.
    $xmpd_db = array(
    1 => array('EA', 'EA_WTRESRVD', 'EMERGENCY SERVICE CALL', '000.10'),
    2 => array('EA', 'EA_WTRESRV', 'EMERGENCY SERVICE CALL AFTER HOURS', '000.20')

    );

  $search_result = array_column($xmpd_db, $column_value, $column_index);

  return $search_result[$xmc];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you need is...

```
$search_result = array_column($xmpd_db, 3, 1);
```

What this is doing is taking the 3rd(actually the 4th as it's zero based) field (the price field) and indexing it by the 1st(i.e. the 2nd) column.

So `$search_result` ends up as

```
Array

    (
        [WTRESRVD] => 122.67
        [WTRESRV] => 184.00
    )
```

To expand on the code...

```
function getField_Target($xmc, $column_index = 1, $column_value = 3)
    {
    // Key values MUST ALWAYS BE UNIQUE.
    // Values on the left.
    $xmpd_db = array(
    1 => array('EA', 'WTRESRVD', 'EMERGENCY SERVICE CALL', '122.67'),
    2 => array('EA', 'WTRESRV', 'EMERGENCY SERVICE CALL AFTER HOURS', '184.00')

  );

  $search_result = array_column($xmpd_db, $column_value, $column_index);
  return $search_result[$xmc];

    }
```

So,

```
echo getField_Target('WTRESRV');        // 184.00
echo getField_Target('WTRESRV', 1, 2);  // EMERGENCY SERVICE CALL AFTER HOURS
```

Comment: Sorry - I'm not sure that that means.  Can you give an example of how you call this function, it may help.

Comment: Observe how this line return $search_result[$xmc]; returns not everything but a single value. I need to assign each value in search result to their own variables for later use. Like a SELECT query if you would.

Comment: getField_UnitPrice('WTRESRVD');

Comment: return '122.67';

Comment: If `$xmc` contained 'WTRSERV', then when it gets to the return, it would pick out the 184 value.  All I'm suggesting is to replace this line in your code.

Comment: Now, I want to return any corresponding index to the LEFT or RIGHT of the code I am using to search.

Comment: I've updated, this allows you to index by any column and return any other column, I've added a few examples.